# Create Account and Mint Token using solana-keygen grind

Tags: spl-token, solana-cli

I am trying to create a token with a vanity address. I have tried the following.

```
solana-keygen grind —starts-with test:1
```

and `test....tg.json` file has been created.
After this, when I run
`spl-token create-account test...tg.json`, it shows `no such file or directory (os error2)`.Which command should I run with to create a token and mint with the vanity keypair json file created?

Answer (score 2):

`spl-token create-account <token-address>` is used to create a token account, so you need to pass the token address, not the wallet address.

You can follow the below steps to achieve what you trying to do

```
# Creates a token and use the token address to create an account 
# or use any existing token address
spl-token create-token --decimals 0
```

```
# Creates the token account associated to given token address,
# if the vanity address is set to default Keypair path in Solana config
# you can exclude the --owner flag
spl-token create-account <token-address> --owner <vanity-address>
```

Answer (score 2):

as already mentioned in another answer

```
spl-token create-account
```

is used to create token accounts.

What you want to do is creating a new mint account.
For that you can use

```
spl-token create-token <vanityKeypair.json>
```

This way the token mint (which is what we know as the token address) will be the address of the vanity keypair.

easy as that ;)